# How to use Google API to Query Index folders using Python

Tags: python, google-search-api

I am new to programming and currently learning Python. I wanted your help to figure if there is a way to query/traverse/search inside  index folder returned by a Google query using Python.

Let me try to give an example:

suppose based on a query, Google returns me a link to a index folder like ftp ://path/to/index/directory

I want to traverse the files available at that index and fetch me a specific file.

Is this possible with Google Search API?

Thank you